# wordpress menu, post and pages appeared triple after transferred hosting

Tags: wordpress, duplicates, wordpress-theming

Hi I just moved hosting from Bluehost to Wealthy Affiliate. I used a paid theme called Streamstore. But now I have all my menu, page and post appear 3 times in my site.

My site shows all my menu 3 times, when I go to WP admin, the display says I have 33 pages where there are only visible 11 pages???? I can't even find them to delete them. Posts are just the same, I have 100 posts, but now they are all tripled so it shows I have 300 posts.

Where can I find the duplication and delete them for good please?

Answer (score 0):

Click "All Posts" and "All Pages" in your admin dashboard, and check this tabs:

[image]

and this one for pages

[image]

Usually this is where your posts could hide. If not, then most probably you have duplicated your database records, but that's not such a common issue. If needed I will explain what to do in that case.

Comment: Hi Haris, thank  you for this is not the case unfortunately. I see the post count and page count as per above, my post showing 300, but I only got 100, I have emptied everything in Trash, and there's no post in Draft and Pending AT ALL.

Comment: Then something must be wrong with your MySQL database. Are you familiar with it?